# No Activity found to handle Intent (activity was declared in application manifest)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

I believe I have read all of the similar questions (of which there are many).
Most of them simply said to make sure the activity is (properly) declared in the application's AndroidManifest.xml (done) and that your requested intent and declared intent filters both contain the default category, Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT (done).

I am in the process of moving some activities that were in an application project into a library project (that the application references). They were referenced explicitly (by class name), and I'm now trying to refer to them implicitly (via action name, data mime type, and category). Unfortunately, my attempt to start the activity is generating the exception with the detail message in the subject line.

Here is the activity declaration in the application's androidmanifest.xml (within the application node):

```
<activity android:name="com.everyscape.android.panoramaui.ESPhotoViewActivity" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.everyscape.android.panoramaui.action.VIEW_WORLDTAG"/>
        <data android:mimeType="@string/IMAGE_MIME_TYPE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here's the code that attempts to launch that activity:

```
Context context = this.getContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(ESViewWorldTagActivity.ACTION_VIEW_WORLDTAG);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(dataURL);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, dataMimeType);
intent.putExtra(ESPhotoViewActivity.EXTRA_WORLDTAG_TITLE, title);
intent.putExtra(ESPhotoViewActivity.EXTRA_WORLDTAG_ID, worldTagId);
intent.putExtra(ESPhotoViewActivity.EXTRA_PANORAMA_ID,panoID);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

In the past - I started the activity by using an explicit intent.
This is the first time I am using an implicit intent.
I don't want to use an explicit intent - because I want the application to be able to override the activity that is used (and the code to launch the activity is in a library - it is not supposed to be application specific).

Here is the exception that I am getting:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.everyscape.android.panoramaui.action.VIEW_WORLDTAG cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=http://ugc.everyscape.com//WT2/BF/EWW-Q-0A1E.JPG typ=image/* flg=0x8 (has extras) }
```

How can I diagnose and resolve this exception?

Thanks,
Chuck

Comment: I'd start by putting an actual MIME type in `android:mimeType`, instead of a string resource reference, and see if that helps.

Comment: Good idea. First I tried moving the string reference from the library to the application. Then I tried using an actual MIME type directly in AndroidManifest.xml. Neither change solved the problem - I still get an exception about activity not found.

Comment: You could try adding `android:scheme="http"` to the `<data>` element, though I would not expect this to be needed.